# XLST remove an specific fragment based in a attributte

Tags: xml, xslt

Using the following xml and xslt I want to remove an specific fragment based in a specific math and conditions.

XML

```
<root>
  <component>.....</component>
  <table> 
   <entry>
      <extra>....</extra> 
      <reference value="#MED_0"/>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <extra>....</extra> 
      <reference value="#MED_1"/>
   </entry>
  </table>   
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template name="remove" match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[name()='entry']">
    <xsl:if test="@value='#MED_0'">
        <xsl:call-template name="remove"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Current Result

```
<root>
  <component>.....</component>
  <table> 
  </table>   
</root>
```

Expected

```
<root>
  <component>.....</component>
  <table> 
   <entry>
      <extra>....</extra> 
      <reference value="#MED_1"/>
   </entry>
  </table>   
</root>
```

When we execute it with XSLT version 1.0 it remove all the entry but we just want to remove all the entry with value="#MED_0" not with value="#MET_1"

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove elements by matching them with empty templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry[reference[@value='#MED_0']]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```